# Venn diagram numbers adding up correctly

Tags: probability

"A survey of 386 businessmen showed that 255 lived in mansions, 152 owned yachts, and 110 lived in mansions and owned yachts."

How do the numbers add up (if they do at all) in this question? I get $255+152-110\neq386$. Is my calculation incorrect or is there contradictory information in the statement of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $110$ businessmen who own yachts and mansions, then you have $152-110$ who own just yachts, and $255-110$ who own just mansions. Then the total is $42+145+110 = 297$. Then you presumably have $99$ businessmen who own neither mansions nor yachts.

The important thing here is to remember that you can have businessmen 'outside' the two overlapping circles of the venn diagram, but still within your [universe](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/venndiag.htm): if you have the two sets $M = \{$businessmen who own mansions$\}$ and $Y = \{$businessmen who own yachts$\}$, then don't forget that not all businessmen have to be in $M \cup Y$.